# PHPUNIT - Returns the same instance of a class I instantiate 2 times

Tags: php, phpunit

I need help please because I am not an expert at PHPUNIT.

I feel that when I instantiate my Validator twice in my test class, that PHPUNIT ignores the 2nd instance ...

Here is my code:
```php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Validation;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Validation\Validator;

class ValidatorTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIsNotValid()
    {
        $_POST['input_test'] = '1';

        $validator = new Validator();

        $validator->rules([
            'input_test' => [
                'alpha '=> true,  // "$_POST['input_test']" must be alpha
            ],
        ]);

        // "isValid()" must return "false", and PHPUNIT returns "false"
        $this->assertFalse($validator->isValid());

        // "count($validator->getErrors())" Must return "1", and PHPUNIT returns "1"
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($validator->getErrors()));
    }

    public function testIsValid()
    {
        $_POST['input_test'] = 'aaa';

        $validator = new Validator();

        $validator->rules([
            'input_test' => [
                'alpha' => true,  // "$_POST['input_test']" must be alpha
            ],
        ]);

       // "isValid()" must return "true", but PHPUNIT returns "false"
        $this->assertTrue($validator->isValid());

        // "count($validator->getErrors())" must return "0", but PHPUNIT returns "1"
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($validator->getErrors()));
    }

}
```

```
So my test "testIsValid()" does not work properly. On the other hand, if I delete the test "testIsNotValid()", the test "testIsValid()" starts to work ...

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, provide more information. What output are you get and what are you expect? Can you show the code of `rules()` and `isValid()` methods?

Comment: I posted the methods in my 2nd answer. What I get and what I expect are explained in the comments of my 1st answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank, here my validator class :

```
<?php

class Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Name du input
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $input;

    /**
     * Valeur des rules qu'on passe à un input
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * POST ou GET - Sera à POST par defaut
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private $requestMethod;

    /**
     * Contiendra les éventuels erreurs
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $errors = [];

    /**
     * Validator constructor.
     *
     * @param null $requestMethod
     */
    public function __construct()
    {        
        $this->requestMethod = $_POST;
    }

    /**
     * Vérification des données soumises
     *
     * @param array $array
     */
    public function rules(array $array)
    {
        foreach ($array as $input => $rules) {
            $this->input = $input;

            if (is_array($rules)) {                
                foreach ($rules as $rule => $value) {
                    if ($rule != 'label') {
                        if ($rule == 'required' || $rule == 'file' || isset($this->requestMethod[$this->input])) {
                            $this->value = $value;

                            $this->callRule($rule);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Appeler la règle de validation
     *
     * @param string $rule
     */
    protected function callRule(string $rule)
    {
        $methodVerify = 'verify'.Str::convertSnakeCaseToCamelCase($rule);

        if (method_exists($this, $methodVerify)) {
            $this->$methodVerify();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Vérifier que valeur entrée dans le champ est bien alphabétique
     */
    private function verifyAlpha()
    {
        if ($this->value === true && !preg_match(self::REGEX_ALPHA, $this->requestMethod[$this->input])) {
            $this->errors[$this->input] = $this->pushError('alpha');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return bool - True si formulaire soumis est valide, false si pas valide
     */
    public function isValid(): bool
    {
        return count($this->errors) === 0;
    }
}
```

Thank you